# Apache Pig Allocation & Parsing Issue With Count

Tags: java, apache-pig, hortonworks-sandbox

currently learning Apache Pig with Hadoop and using a huge data set of 62million. Just trying to do a normal COUNT function and continually get errors. I have 8gigs of RAM allocated and I could easily do it with HIVE, but seem to get parsing issues or heap allocation issues, its different every time. I'm using hadoop on top of a virtual machine.

The errors are:

> file script.pig, line 3, column 39> Failed to generate logical plan.
>   Nested exception:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070:
>   Could not resolve count using imports: [, java.lang.,
>   org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>
> ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. Could not resolve count using imports: [, java.lang.,
>   org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>
> ERROR 1070: Could not resolve count using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>
> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve count using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin.,
>   org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

My Pig Code

```
a = LOAD 'bigData_orc' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = group a ALL;
c = foreach b generate group as rap, count(a) as counter;
dump c;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset my environment variables to their original state. I then reset the admin password, logged in as admin, and ran updated all environment variables through Ambari. Ambari was helpful enough to shoot over other variables that needed more space allocation as well. Was able to up my heap allocation up to 20GB's of RAM & was able to count all 68 million rows via Pig.

Answer (score 3):

> Could not resolve count

Try to capitalize the `COUNT()` Pig function

Comment: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias c. Backend error : Vertex failed, vertexName=scope-12, vertexId=vertex_1472055054077_0021_1_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1472055054077_0021_1_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Fatal Error cause TezChild exit.:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: I did capitalize count, but seems like i have another heap space error.

Comment: That is unrelated to your first error, so now you have a problem with loading 62 million records of text into YARN on the Sandbox VM (hint: that runs out of space very quickly)

Comment: cricket_007:  I haven't had any issues before, when using filter or using a foreach to generate occurrences, but for some reason now I'm having heap issues.

Comment: cricket_007: Also, why would HIVE work for counting up all data pts but not pig if memory allocation on the heap was an issue?

Comment: Is your Hive running Tez or Mapreduce?

Comment: Hive is running on Tez so is Pig. But currently I'm executing them individually

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, but don't you want to `COUNT(b)` ? You grouped `a` on all the data, so I don't understand why you are trying to produce the full record count for all the data on each group